# CSS <img> relative positioning vs. background-image + background-position

Tags: css

I'm working on a thumbnail page for an image gallery. Thumbnail previews are done as an `<ul>` with floating `<li>` with a fixed, square size.

The thumbnails images *themselves* however are not necessarily square or same size, they have the properties of the large images they represent.

To make it look nice I'd like to display the center of the thumbnail image in the square `<li>`, cutting off an equal amount of overflow left and right (see *fig. 1*):

```
 +..+---------+..+                +---------+....+
 ://|  /\_/\  |//:                |     /\_/|////:
 ://| ( o.o ) |//:                |    ( o.o|////:
 ://|  > ^ <  |//:                |     > ^ |////:
 ://| {o___o} |//:                |    {o___|////:
 +..+---------+..+                +---------+....+
          (fig. 1)                        (fig. 2)
```

I can do this by removing the `<img>` tag and defining (CSS sprite):

```
<li style="width: x; height: x; overflow: hidden;">
   <div style="background: url(...) no-repeat center center;"/>
</li>
```

This works and looks nice but only when you have CSS enabled. Plus it's not very semantic since the image is not displayed by an `<img>` tag.

When I use an `<img>` tag in place of the inner `<div>` above, things look more like in *fig. 2*.

How would I move the `<img>` via CSS to always be centered, no matter how wide the thumbnail image actually is? I assume some sort of relative positioning might do it, but a naïve `position: relative; left: -50%;` does not work.

---

*P.S.: Yes, I know that I could make all the thumbnails square, assume that this is not the answer I'm looking for.*

Comment: +1 for the great ascii art alone :) I assume you don't know the width(s) of each individual thumbnail at the time you are defining this?

Comment: Haha :) ASCII art nicely done !

Comment: @Pekka: No I don't. I could find out, but a generic solution is more attractive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS [`clip` property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pos_clip.asp) comes to mind but I don't think it's possible to achieve a centered square with it without knowing the image's dimensions. The cleanest way would probably be finding out the thumbnail's dimensions on server side, and then apply a `clip` with  absolute pixel values on it so it becomes square.

Assuming getting the image sizes isn't an option (I gather you wouldn't be asking if it were), one workaround idea comes to mind. I can't build a test case right now, but something in this direction *might* work:

- Inside the square `li`, place a `div` with a fixed width that will never be reached by your image (e.g. 1000 pixels) and give it a `position: relative; left: -{x}px`, `x`  being ("the fixed width of the div element" / 2) - "width of the square li element"
- Give the `div` `text-align: center` (You might also need `align="center"` to cater for IE6)
- Place the `img` inside the `div`
- It should be positioned centered.

not pretty, but not overly horrible, either.

Comment: `x` being ("the fixed width of the div element" / 2) - "width of the li element"

Comment: +1 This works and fits nicely with my already existing markup. I did not even have to add another `<div>`. But alas, I'm running into problems with IE7/8 who do not hide the overflow correctly. :-\

Comment: Ha! Success! :-) Obviously this was something that had to do with giving the container layout. Adding `position: relative;` to the square  `<img>` container made the overflow disappear correctly on IE. Thank you! :-) PS: it must be "minus *half* the width of the square li element".