# How to center a list of images?

Tags: html, css

How to center 3 images in a row at 480px screen width, and 2 images at 320px?

Here is [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qfrRG/)

```
<ul>
    <li><img/></li>
    ...
</ul>

@media (max-width: 480px) {} 
@media (max-width: 320px) {}
```

Comment: before calculate as percent according to screen size.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3820610/18771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this does the job:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/qfrRG/4/

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    /* would like 3 centered images in a row */
    img {width: 30%; margin-left: 2%;}
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    /* would like 2 centered images in a row */
    img {width: 45%; margin-left: 5%}
}
```

Adjust widths and margins to suit.

Answer (score 3):

Put a `display: inline-block;` on your `<li>` and `text-align: center;` on your `<ul>`. This way your images will allways be center aligned. In your media queries you can set the width of your `<ul>` (`display: block;`) so you'll have the correct amount of images lined next to each other.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/qfrRG/2/

Comment: The only problem with this solution is the last row - in my case I need it to be aligned to left side of previous rows ( like when the number of images is not even). The same with Per Salbark's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qfrRG/8/) something like what you were looking for?
Just beware it uses some attributes that aren't available in old browsers. Specifically `nth-child()`;